# on VBA, how can I setup a UDP client to connect to my local network?

Tags: vba, udp

There's lot of info on this for VB.net, but I can't seem to find an example script for VBA to connect to a 127.0.0.1 with a port of my choosing (eg. 1234).

I know this may seem like a noob question, but I've recently had to transfer over to use VBA.

Comment: Take a look at the [winsock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733709(v=vs.60).aspx) control